# laravel homestead downgrade to mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, laravel, homestead

I have laravel homestead installed and originally it had mysql 5.7 installed. I subsequently updated my yaml file by included the following and running `vagrant reload --provision`

```
features:
 - mysql8: true
```

Now I want to downgrade back to mysql 5.7 however simply removing the the above and re-running `vagrant reload --provision` does not downgrade back to 5.7

How do I downgrade back to 5.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to destroy the existing instance and start it again with mysql8 set to false.

In your Homestead.yaml (you can also remove mysql8 parameter)

```
...

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
    - mysql8: false
...
```

Destroy and start again:

```
~\Homestead > vagrant box destroy
~\Homestead > vagrant up
```

NOTE: Make sure backup databases if you have any before destroying.

Answer (score 6):

The current answer [is no longer true](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/downgrading-mysql-in-laravel-homestead?page=1#reply=671674) for Homestead v11, [you need to go back to v10](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1460#issuecomment-766933947) as MySQL is no longer compatible with the underlying VB.

I used the options

```
features:
  - mysql: true
  - mysql8: false
```

and this is the result:

[image]

The following works: check out the [latest v10.x](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases) version of the Homestead repo (v10.17.0 in this case):

```
git checkout v10.17.0
```

update the repo

```
composer update
```

Make sure you set the `features` in your yaml file as above and rebuild Homestead:

```
homestead destroy && homestead up
```

It should use or download the latest ['laravel/homestead' vagrant box](https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead) version 9.x.
Now Homestead should have MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Thanks a million, this worked for me switching the version from release to v10