# How to change MYSQL version 8 to 5.7 in Laravel homestead using Homestead.yaml file per project?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I installed the **homestead** per project.

- Laravel version **8**.
- OS version **ubuntu 20.04**.
- After installation of a homestead by following this link `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#per-project-installation`, when I logged into the vagrant box using `vagrant ssh` and then check the **MYSQL** version using `MySQL --version` it shows this `MySQL  Ver 8.0.21 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`.

After following this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189727/laravel-homestead-downgrade-to-mysql-5-7` it happens nothing and remain version 8.

**Expectation**

Just change the feature list and vagrant box act accordingly like when I add the text below

```
   -
       mariadb: false
   -
       ohmyzsh: false
   -
       webdriver: false
```

**MySQL** version will automatically fallback to **MySQL 5.7**